# Why use 甩 twice?

Tags: word-choice

Probably an impossible question to answer, just a style thing, but why did the writer use 甩 twice?

“在台上，你的手是不是被什么东西扎了一下？ 快结束时我看你微微甩了甩手，你平时被东西扎着时就是这样子。“

我看你微微甩了甩手 I saw you flick your hand slightly (I suppose I could write: I saw you give a slight flick of your hand 'a flick of your hand': （一个）甩手)

Would 微微甩了手 be acceptable?

Comment: see grammars on repetition of verbs,  动词的重叠，（discussed repeatedly at this site before)甩了甩手 is
the 动词的重叠 form of 甩了手, difference in meaning discussed before and in any grammar

Comment: Thanks, but the question remains: Why??

Comment: in this case b/c of preceding 微微 there may not be much difference, but "why" could be answered by the meaning of verb repetition, which has been discussed before.

Comment: Why so cagey? If you know why, why not say so?

Comment: I am a native speaker, I do not think you need to be entangled with this.

Comment: It would be a matter of copying from grammars again, in fact this user copied the corresponding section （explaining usage and meaning) from ＂外国人实用汉语语法＂once, but unable to locate the corresponding question, anyhow for such basic grammar there are other online resources

Comment: @bios I know it is more or less useless to ask "Why?" in matters of grammar and expression, but I just have to ask sometimes. Somewhere there must be an explanation!

Comment: just located: see comment #1 at ［link］（http://chinese.stackexchange.com/search?q=What+is+the+meaning+of+%E6%84%A3%E4%BA%86%E6%84%A3）

Answer (score 1):

Referred from another site: "汉语有些动词可以重叠使用，用来表示短时、尝试或反复多次，带有一种轻松的口气。" (http://www.chinaqw.com/hwjy/hykt/200806/11/119975.shtml)

I translate it as:

In Mandarin, some verbs can be used in an overlapping/repetitive way to signify short-time action, trying something or do something again and again, accompanied with a soft and relaxed tone.

For this ABAB-like structure, sometimes you can map it as "A+ed a bit/slightly", use -ed because it's a past action, besides the time period is really really short like in no time(practically or emotionally you want to de-emphasize the action).

1. 甩了甩手 -> flicked his hand a bit/slightly.
2. 他看了看手表 -> he took a quick look at his watch. (a quick look still has some meaning of 'slightly' to me)
3. 奥巴马拉了拉领带 -> Obama slightly pulled his tie.

   but 奥巴马 doesn't 打了打领带, 打领带 really takes time.
4. Jack 打了打篮球. -> I want to emotionally de-emphasize the action 打篮球 here, I think he didn't play for a long time, maybe made some shots and left and that's it.

And some opposite examples:

1. 我吃了吃饭. also, 我喝了喝水, 我上了上班

   Wrong, it violates the "short-time" action rule, since nobody can have dinner in no time, the same for work(上班)

   So you only say 我吃（完/过）饭了. 我上（完/过）班了.
2. 他正在眨了眨眼. 正在: be doing sth. 眨眼: blink

   Wrong, ABAB usually don't fit the progressive tense, better as a past simple tense

   So you can say: 他眨了眨眼

To comprehend ABAB structure, you will need a whole book, but hope these simple rules helps you out a bit.

Comment: Aha, it indicates a short period. Double verb = less time? That makes sense in my context anyhow, thanks. A bit preempted by 微微 though. Normally, double word = more of: 大大的， 微微的 Interesting!

Answer (score 0):

user6065 is right about the grammar of course.

As far as your question about why the writer would use reduplication of 甩 in addition to a separate adverb like 微微， I'm not sure there's a better answer than "that's what Chinese speakers like to do."  I'm not a native speaker, but I've lived in (southern) China for a good while. Based on the ear test, I'm not sure I've actually ever heard someone say 微微， while I hear reduplication of verbs to express the that meaning all the time.

When it comes to word choice, I heartily endorse the principle of mindless conformity.  Until we reach fluency, we second language learners are the slaves, native speakers are the masters, and we should always remember that!

Comment: Haha! You've acquired a Chinese mind-set: 奴性, which is why the Chinese are so good at organizing mass movements!

Comment: Heh.  I'm pretty sure most of my Chinese acquaintances would disagree.  But I do think in the case of acquiring a 2nd language it's the proper orientation to have.

Comment: It's a remnant from 封建时代, so I've been told by my Chinese friends.